# after working in local server, how to move OpenERP on a remote server?

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, odoo

I installed OpenERP V 7 on my local machine. I made ​​modification in the CSS. I also remove some menu, change the labels of some windows and change the position of some menus (one after the other in the order decided by the customer).

The work required is over and runs well on the premises. Now I'm looking for a way to move my work on the server while keeping the changes. Knowing that I worked directly through the interface of OpenERP.

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a generally accepted way of doing customization in openerp. Ususally, you should make a custom module that implements your customization when installed on the OpenERP server installation.

Are you using Windows or Linux? The concept here is to move all of the server addons files to the upsite server, including a dump of the database which can be restored on the upsite server.

Here's how. 
First click the Manage databases at the login screen,
Do a backup database and save the generated dump file.

Install openerp o nthe upsite server (*major versions must match).
Copy the server addons folder, and upload to the upsite server's addon directory.
Restart openerp service.
Then restore the dump file from your backup location.

This is basically how you can mirror a "customized" openerp installation across servers.

Hope this helps.